# Websphere 6.1 - Precompile jsp files

Tags: jsp, websphere, performance

What is the best way to precompile JSP files in Websphere (6.1)?

I have looked at other questions related to JSP precompilations, but as each AppServer has specific settings, I would like to know specifically a solution for Websphere.

I found some references in the net to edit the file ibm-web-ext.xmi:

```
Add the following line before the line
    ...
    </webappext:WebAppExtension>:  
    <jspAttributes
    xmi:id="JSPAttribute_2" name="disableJspRuntimeCompilation" value="true"/>

    # Run the JSP batch compiler.
    WAS_installDir/bin/JspBatchCompiler -ear.path /mytmp/WC_jbweb1.expanded.ear -webmodule.name Stores.war -compileToWebInf true
```

I am looking for some solution to precompile JSP's on deployment and not using the batch compiler.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the console, you can choose the option as described here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/info/aes/ae/trun_app_instwiz.html

```
Applications > Install New Application > application_path > Show me all installation options and parameters > Next > Next > Precompile JavaServer Pages files > Next > Step: Provide options to compile JSPs.
```